# Using/ Extracting data from Interpolating Functions returned from NDEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, interpolation, eigenvalues

I am relatively new to Mathematica and have been trying to use the NDEigensystem command to work with some quantum systems. I am able to get the accurate energy eigenvalues but am having problems with eigenfunctions; more specifically, I am having trouble actually calling values using the interpolating functions.

```
m2 = 0.5;
ℏ = 1;
w = 0.5;
\[ScriptCapitalO]2 = -ℏ^2/(2 m2) Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
  1/2 m2 w^2 (x^2 + y^2) u[x, y];
```

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalO]2, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 28,
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}}];
```

As we can see above, I am using a simple 2d harmonic oscillator as my Hamiltonian, and then using the NDEigensystem command I am generating eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. I am able to get the right eigenvalues for my system as we can see below
[image: Energy Eigen Values]

However; the eigenfunctions aren't usable, I am trying to extract the data from the interpolating functions to no avail. From what I understand the syntax is:

```
ψ = funs[[1]]
ψ[2,3]
```

The above code should print the values of the first eigenfunction as {2,3} but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm hoping to eventually integrate these functions to calculate expectation values, I would be very grateful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Use `ReplaceAll` to inject values for `x` and `y`:

```
funs[[1]] /. {x -> 2, y -> 3}
```

> ```
> -0.0555609
> ```

**2.** Construct pure functions (`funs2`) from `funs`:

```
funs2 = Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ funs;

funs2[[1]][2, 3]
```

> ```
> -0.0555609
> ```

**3.** use `u` instead of `u[x,y]` in the second argument of `NDEigensystem`

```
ClearAll[vals, funs3]
{vals, funs3} = NDEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalO]2, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 28, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> 
    {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}}];

funs3[[1]][2, 3]
```

> ```
> -0.0555609
> ```

```
Plot3D[funs3[[1]][x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@Through[funs3[[{1, 2, 5, 10, 15}]][x, y]], 
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> (Row[{"funs3[[", #, "]][x,y]"}] & /@ {1, 2, 5, 10, 15}), 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much for the detailed and prompt response. You're a real lifesaver, this is working perfectly.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you would be able to help me out again. I was able to use this command perfectly to get the functions but am having some trouble integrating them. Something as basic as this command:
funs2 = Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ funs;
\[Psi]1 = funs2[[1]];
\[Psi]2 = funs2[[2]];
a = NIntegrate[\[Psi]1 \[Psi]2, {x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}] isn't giving any results.

Comment: @rahulmenon, try `a = NIntegrate[[Psi]1[x,y] [Psi]2[x,y], {x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]`?