# Using NIntegrate with interpolating function

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, interpolation, finite-element-method

I am relatively new to Mathematica and have been trying to use the NDEigensystem command to work with some quantum systems. This is actually inline with a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225353/using-extracting-data-from-interpolating-functions-returned-from-ndeigensystem) I had asked about a week back. I am able to use the NDEigensystem command to get the eigen values and eigen functions, here is the basic model I'm testing this with:

```
m2 = 0.5;
ℏ = 1;
w = 0.5;
\[ScriptCapitalO]2 = -ℏ^2/(2 m2) Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
  1/2 m2 w^2 (x^2 + y^2) u[x, y];
```

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalO]2, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 28,
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}}];
```

Using the answer to my previous question I am able to get the eigenfunctions as functions as shown below; however, I am still unable to use them with NIntegrate for some reason:

```
funs2 = Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ funs;
\[Psi]1 = funs2[[1]];
\[Psi]2 = funs2[[2]];
Ans = NIntegrate[\[Psi]1 x \[Psi]2,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]
```

The last command doesn't return anything and just gives me back the command line again. I am not certain where I am going wrong. Would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation. [This is from the ref page of NDEigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html#1729336659)

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], u[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, 4]

NIntegrate[#^2, {x, 0, \[Pi]}] & /@ funs

(* {1., 1., 0.999995, 1.} *)
```

Note that the argument `u[x]` to `NDEigensystem` tells `NDEigensystem` that the resulting interpolating functions will also have the independent variable `x` as in `InterpolatingFunction[data][x]`. If `u` were given as an argument the result would be `InterpolatingFunction[data]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for the late response, had fallen a little ill. This definitely works

Comment: @rahulmenon, no worries. I hope you are feeling better.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

m2 = 1/2;
ℏ = 1;
w = 1/2;
\[ScriptCapitalO]2 = -ℏ^2/(2 m2) Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
   1/2 m2 w^2 (x^2 + y^2) u[x, y];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalO]2, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 28, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> \
{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5}}}}];

funs2 = Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ funs;

ψ1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := funs2[[1]][x, y];
ψ2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := funs2[[2]][x, y];
```

Verifying that the functions evaluate

```
#[1, 1] & /@ {ψ1, ψ2}

(* {-0.21977, 0.104243} *)
```

The integrand is

```
Plot3D[
 ψ1[x, y]*ψ2[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

The min and max are

```
#[{ψ1[x, y]*ψ2[x, y], -5 < x < 5, -5 < y < 5},
   {x, y}] & /@ {NMinimize, NMaximize}

(* {{-0.0482587, {x -> -0.397854, y -> 1.35926}}, {0.0482587, {x -> 0.397854, 
   y -> -1.35926}}} *)
```

From the symmetry, the integral is expected to be near zero

```
Ans = NIntegrate[ψ1[x, y]*ψ2[x, y],
   {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] // Quiet

(* 6.8028*10^-13 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I seem to have a solution that works for now, but I do planning on using a loop and this might get a little hard to incorporate into the same, so if anyone has any better ideas please do let me know. I explicitly defined an Integrand as a function of x and y and was able to integrate the functions after that

```
Integrand[x_,y_] = \[Psi]1[x,y] x \[Psi]2[x,y]
NIntegrate[Integrand[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

Using this method Mathematica returned a value for this numerical integration.